# Flutter google sign in serverAuthCode

Tags: flutter, google-signin

I'm using this flutter [plugin google_sign_in 5.2.1](https://pub.dev/packages/google_sign_in)

works good I get the response

```
{displayName: Mario Mc, email: myemail@gmail.com, id: 117816213074325689769, photoUrl: https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/a-/AOh14GgyaPy7ik693hjyIBmtW5IRXUdCXluaeI=s96-c, serverAuthCode: 4/0AX4XfWiqJ1DMfPaDbgf6gOFVMCfgMicyPqGk25bxjKfA4wq7bJCCu-TWRB8c3rAz_g}
```

My question is: what is serverAuthCode?
And what's id: 117816213074325689769 used for

And after I send that serverAuthCode to the server, how do I verify that code is legit by calling google servers(as you know any person can send a fake serverAuthCode, so we need to verify it before saving it or do something with it)

I want to use PHP in the server side
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is use this to get the accessToken then send it to the server

```
                    // sign In With Google 
                    _googleSignIn.signIn().then((userData) { 
                      userData.authentication.then((googleKey) {
                        setState(() { 
                          // Retrieve the email from Google auth 
                          googleEmail = userData.email;
                          googleId = userData.id;
                          googlePhotoUrl = userData.photoUrl;
                          googleServerAuthCode = userData.serverAuthCode;
                          googleAccessToken = googleKey.accessToken;
                          googleIdToken = googleKey.idToken;
                        });
                        print("googleAccessToken");
                        print(googleAccessToken);
                        // call your login function if no errors
                        checkInternetAndLoginWithGoogle();
                      }).catchError((err) {
                        print('inner error');
                      });
                    }).catchError((err) {
                      print('error occurred');
                      print(err);
                    });
```

in the server side, you can verify that access token by calling

```
https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/tokeninfo?access_token=<access token>
```

you will get an answer if that token is valid or expired

Also, you can call this to get user info such as name, email, photo etc.

```
https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/userinfo?access_token=<access token>
```